# Nginx: redirect default website http to https

Tags: nginx

I have a website, that could have unknown amount of CNAME DNS records linked to it. What I need is to have ANY http requests to be redirected to https. We will be using a default certificate. No matter if it IP address or DNS name typed in the browser - all need to be forwarded to https

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

I have tried `$server_name` as well.. If I go to http:// it redirects me to "https://_". Is there any equivalent to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` in Apache?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html take a look at the regex match. Define a regex for the server name and you can then use it as a variable. in the return value

Answer (score 2):

It seems that nginx is having equivalent to HTTP_HOST in Apache. So this works for me:

```
return         301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do a Nginx redirect is with HTTP 301, not a rewrite. See [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites).

As far as your server setup goes, see mine below. I define the server name on port 80, then redirect to HTTPS on port 443. Everything (SSL settings, root, index, etc...) is applied under this HTTPS server block.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;                       #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:80;                                 #Listen on IPv6
        server_name loganmarchione.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;           #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy;                            #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;                       #Listen on IPv6

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/unified2.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-private-decrypted.key;

        ...
```

Comment: is it `$host` or `$http_host`? I need to get the requested host by user in his browser and seems `$host` returns the server name, which set on the server

Comment: See here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx